# Why I cannot get heatmap only for the dates in my data, R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, calendar, heatmap

I am trying to create a calendar heatmap but get all the days plotted for 2021. Yet, want to plot only for the days I have in the data set. From 2020 whole year and until 2021 Feb. This is done in R.

This is a fake data I have:

I am using calendarHeat from github:

```
source("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iascchen/VisHealth/master/R/calendarHeat.R")
```

And the actual code is this:

```
r2g <- c("#D61818", "#FFAE63", "#FFFFBD", "#B5E384")

calendarHeat(occ_abv_18$date, occ_abv_18$oc_18, ncolors = 99, color = "r2g", varname="Occupancy over 18")
```

I do not understand why I do not get the heatmap? Is there a way to fix this or any other solutions are welcome? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column name is 'Date' and not `date` (based on the OP's code)

```
calendarHeat(dates = occ_abv_18$Date, values = occ_abv_18$oc_18, 
      ncolors = 99, color = "r2g", varname="Occupancy over 18")
```

-output

[image]

---

Regarding the OP'c comments about date range, it is the line in the `calendarHeat` function

```
...
min.date <- as.Date(paste(format(min(dates), "%Y"),
                    "-1-1",sep = ""))
max.date <- as.Date(paste(format(max(dates), "%Y"),
                     "-12-31", sep = ""))
...
```

does the floor/ceiling by year for `min/max`

---

Therefore, if we change the function by changing those lines to

```
body(calendarHeat)[[7]] <- quote(min.date <- min(dates))
body(calendarHeat)[[8]] <- quote(max.date <- max(dates))
```

it would work

```
calendarHeat(dates = occ_abv_18$Date, values = occ_abv_18$oc_18, 
      ncolors = 99, color = "r2g", varname="Occupancy over 18")
```

-output

[image]

---

If we need to change the order of colors in 'r2g', then change the `body` element 22

```
body(calendarHeat)[[22]] <- quote(r2g <- rev(c("#D61818", "#FFAE63", "#FFFFBD", "#B5E384")))
```

applying the function

```
calendarHeat(dates = occ_abv_18$Date, values = occ_abv_18$oc_18, 
      ncolors = 99, color = "r2g", varname="Occupancy over 18")
```

-output

[image]

Comment: the problem is that it does plot the days I do not need.

Comment: @GaB your description as I read is `do not understand why I do not get the heatmap?`

Comment: I have changed the title! Sorry about that

Comment: @GaB Based on the data showed, `range(occ_abv_18$Date)#
[1] "2020-01-02" "2021-02-22"`. Not clear what you meant

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of the empty days in the heat map?

Comment: Again, I am very sorry for this. Updated again the post

Comment: @GaB I updated the post.  It is function you need to make the changes.  I changed at two places, and now it is showing the output in a different way.  Likewise, for your custom case, you may need to change the other layers as well

Comment: got these errors:   min.date <- as.Date(paste(format(min(dates), "%Y"),
+                           "-1-1",sep = ""))
Error in min(dates) : invalid 'type' (closure) of argument
> max.date <- as.Date(paste(format(max(dates), "%Y"),
+                           "-12-31", sep = ""))
Error in max(dates) : invalid 'type' (closure) of argument

Comment: @GaB sorry, I can't reproduce it.  I already showed a working solution in the post

Comment: @GaB My code was `body(calendarHeat)[[7]] <- quote(min.date <- min(dates));body(calendarHeat)[[8]] <- quote(max.date <- max(dates))`. The code chunk above it was just to show the actual lines we need to replace.

Comment: and then got this error after running your code:Error in if ((y.last.m) < 6) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In max(dates.fsubs$seq[dates.fsubs$month == j]) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

Comment: @GaB Sorry, I don't know about that.  It is just that I am using your example data and the only code I changed is the `body` two lines and nothing else

Comment: @GaB Have a great day!

Comment: it worked. Now, can I ask you a question. Can the grading be the opposite? Because the lower values gets the stronger color, while the more busier the less. I want the opposite. is there a way ?

Comment: @GaB Can you change the order of colors in `r2g <- c("#D61818", "#FFAE63", "#FFFFBD", "#B5E384")`

Comment: @GaB If you check the source code `#color styles
r2b <- c("#0571B0", "#92C5DE", "#F7F7F7", "#F4A582", "#CA0020") #red to blue                                                                               
r2g <- c("#D61818", "#FFAE63", "#FFFFBD", "#B5E384")   #red to green
w2b <- c("#045A8D", "#2B8CBE", "#74A9CF", "#BDC9E1", "#F1EEF6")   #white to blue
g2r <- c("#B5E384", "#FFFFBD", "#FFAE63", "#D61818") #green to red` these linkes with `r2g` you may want to change